# SVG as data URI triggers XML parsing error in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I made a codepen demo illustrating the problem: [codepen.io/acusti/pen/mJmVRy](http://codepen.io/acusti/pen/mJmVRy)

And here’s the error I get if I try to load the svg content in Firefox:

> XML Parsing Error: unclosed token
>   Location: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20viewBox='0%200%20120%20120'%20version='1.1'%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle%20cx='45'%20cy='45'%20r='30'%20fill='#555555'></circle></svg>`
>   Line Number 1, Column 77:

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 120 120' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle cx='45' cy='45' r='30' fill='
----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Note: I get that error by clicking on the data URI string in the Firefox developer tools (inside the CSS Rules panel while inspecting the `.separator` element), where a tooltip says “Could not load the image”. You can do the same thing by just copy-pasting the Location string from the error message above into your Firefox address bar.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is not valid for data URIs to contain # characters like yours has, you must escape them as %23

The unescaped # character is reserved to indicate the start of a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Firefox is quite right to indicate a parsing error.

Comment: I’d actually checked for that to begin with when I noticed the problem, having seen it mentioned elsewhere, and found that I had no `#` characters in the string. But I hadn’t thought to consider the fill color sass variable I used. Thanks!

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(...)` solved this problem for me.

Comment: Saved me a lot of headache, thanks. Interesting thing, though: In Chrome, Adobe Illustrator and Inkscape, SVG with # character opens/renders flawlessly.

Comment: depends what you're trying to do. If you actually want to use a fragment identifier you basically can't do so with those tools.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the online tool https://www.zhangxinxu.com/sp/svgo/

it support let special characters encoded, such as:

`""` => `%22`
`#` => `%23`
`%` => `%25`
...